# Error when launching using appium

Tags: appium

I am getting an error when I am launching the appium for android. I started node.js by double ckicking node.js then I gave the path of my apk file and then clicked on launch buttonand in console i got following error:

> Starting Node Server
>   Starting Appium in pre-launch
>   Pre-launcing app
>   Using fast reset?false
>   No app-activity desired capability or server param.Parsing from apk.
>   No app-package desired capability or server param.Parsing from apk.
>   Using local app from command line: C:\Users\ssharma\lowes-android-app-Wolverine-Sprint6-2014-04-29_17-03-13.apk
>   Creating new appium session 4aa75228-984f-46f7-8b09-50221dc19875
>   starting android appium
>   Preparing device for session
>   Checking whether app is actually present
>   Checking whether adb is actually present
>   Sent shutdown command,waiting for UiAutomator to stop...
>   Uiautomator did not shut down fast enough calling it gone
>
> Error:
>
> Node Server Process Ended

Please help me in this issue.

Answer (score 0):

What machine are you running on ? On windows you can use exe and on mac you can use app and then pass correct capabilities from appium client.